# Android MVP testing - proper testing presenter login button clicked with valid input

Tags: android, firebase, mockito, firebase-authentication, mvp

So I have a method in my presenter, which I stuck with testing. 
I am using FirebaseAuth to store email and password about users. 
So when I try to login, I proceed with them to get user(if it exists).
I can fetch the userId after success and then, I call a view method, to proceed to other activity with retrieved id.

Here it is:

```
public void loginButtonClicked() {
    if (view != null) {
        if (view.getEmail().trim().equals("") || view.getPassword().trim().equals("")) {
            view.showInputError();
            view.hideProgressBar();
        } else {
            view.showProgressBar();
            view.setLoginProcessAlpha();
            firebaseAuthService.getUserWithEmailAndPassword(view.getEmail(), view.getPassword())
                   .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                              String uid = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                              view.loginSuccesful(uid);
                              view.setLoginNormalAlpha();
                              view.hideProgressBar();
                           }
                       }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Log.d("LoginPresenter", "fail");
                            view.showLoginError(e.getMessage());
                            view.setLoginNormalAlpha();
                            view.hideProgressBar();
                        }
                    });

        }
    }
}
```

I make some simply tests that checks the invalid input:

```
 @Test
public void clickOnLoginButtonWhenEmailAndPasswordInputEmpty_ShowsInputError(){
    when(loginView.getEmail()).thenReturn("");
    when(loginView.getPassword()).thenReturn("");

    loginPresenter.loginButtonClicked();

    verify(loginView).showInputError();
    verify(loginView).hideProgressBar();
}
```

Now I want to write a method to simply check if view.loginSuccesful(someId) is called when it is vaild email/password input. How can i achive this?

```
 @Test
public void clickOnLoginButtonWithValidEmailAndPassword_LoginSuccessfulCalled(){
    when(loginView.getEmail()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_EMAIL);
    when(loginView.getPassword()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_PASSWORD);

    when(firebaseAuthService.getUserWithEmailAndPassword(loginView.getEmail(), loginView.getPassword())) //??????

    loginPresenter.loginButtonClicked();

    verify(loginView).loginSuccesful(someId); ?????????
}
```

I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

So i manage to do this. It requires to change architecture a little, but now everything is clear i think.

Firstly, I've implemented my own custom Callback in the MVP contract interface for Model:

```
 interface Model {

interface GetLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallback {
    void onGetUser(UserDTO userDTO);
}

void getUserByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password, @NonNull GetLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallback getUserByUid);
```

}

Here is now the implementation of FirebaseAuth in the model(not in the presenter, like it was before).

```
@Override
public void getUserByEmailAndPassword(String email, String password, 
@NonNull final GetLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallback 
getLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallback) {
    firebaseAuthService.getUserWithEmail(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    String uid = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                    String displayName = task.getResult().getUser().getDisplayName();
                    String email = task.getResult().getUser().getEmail();

                    UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO(uid, displayName, email);
                    getLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallback.onGetUser(userDTO);
                }
                else{
                    getLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallback.onGetUser(null);
                }
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                getLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallback.onGetUser(null);
            }
        });
```

}

So now, I am hiding the implementation from the presenter. Presenter is only responsible for data transfer between the layers(it can use DTO object).

Finally, here is a method that will be tested in the presenter. Code is now more clear, and also smaller.

```
@Override
public void loginButtonClicked() {
    if(view != null){
        if (view.getEmail().trim().equals("") || 
           view.getPassword().trim().equals("")) {
              view.showInputError();
              view.hideProgressBar();
    } else {
        view.showProgressBar();
        view.setLoginProcessAlpha();
        model.getUserByEmailAndPassword(view.getEmail(), view.getPassword(), new LoginMVP.Model.GetLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onGetUser(UserDTO userDTO) {
                if(userDTO != null){
                    view.loginSuccessful(userDTO.getUid());
                }
                else{
                    view.hideProgressBar();
                    view.showLoginError();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

So, in the structure like this I am able to test things. My test is now working and works like this:

```
@Test
public void clickOnLoginButtonWithValidEmailAndPassword_LoginSuccessfulCalled(){
when(loginView.getEmail()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_EMAIL);
when(loginView.getPassword()).thenReturn(USER_TEST_PASSWORD);

UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO(USER_TEST_ID, USER_TEST_USERNAME, 
USER_TEST_EMAIL);

loginPresenter.loginButtonClicked();

verify(loginModel).getUserByEmailAndPassword(eq(USER_TEST_EMAIL), 
eq(USER_TEST_PASSWORD), getLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallbackCaptor.capture());
getLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallbackCaptor.getValue().onGetUser(userDTO);

verify(loginView).loginSuccessful(userDTO.getUid());
}
```

I used the ArgumentCaptor, which is able to return some values from my mock Callback

```
@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<LoginMVP.Model.GetLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallback> getLoginUserByEmailAndPasswordCallbackCaptor;
```